# Masonry magento overlapping, CSS or JavaScript issue

Tags: magento, jquery-masonry

I am having trouble with masonry and Magento. I am getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

I cannot seem to figure out how to get rid of this issue. I am also getting a overlapping effect. I cannot figure out if I'm missing CSS or even if my JavaScript is working. I have used no conflict.

I would really appreciate help on this, I'm under a bit of pressure to get this sorted now.

Here is the URL:

http://thecheeky.com/testhomepage

Answer (score 0):

This type of error is usually relating to you not closing a javascript function properly.

In your code you have this function:

```
// <![CDATA[

var tpj = jQuery;
tpj.noConflict();

tpj(document).ready(function () {


    tpj(function () {

        var tpjcontainer = tpj('#container-mas');
        tpjcontainer.imagesLoaded(function () {
            tpjcontainer.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.item',
                columnWidth: 240
            });
        });



    // ]]>
```

It's missing the close to the tpj(function () & the document.ready(function... It should look like this:

```
// <![CDATA[

var tpj = jQuery;
tpj.noConflict();

tpj(document).ready(function () {


    tpj(function () {

        var tpjcontainer = tpj('#container-mas');
        tpjcontainer.imagesLoaded(function () {
            tpjcontainer.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.item',
                columnWidth: 240
            });
        });
 });
});


    // ]]>
```

Could be something else but that's a start

Comment: Hi James,

Thanks for the quick replay. Updated my javascript, I still have that error. Any other ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: I just inspected your page again and it looks like the error has now changed to Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded'. imagesLoaded isn't a default jQuery call - it's an additional library found here: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded. I've never used it before but it looks like you're trying to use it and it isn't loaded in your page.